# Order of Galois group divides the degree of the extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I keep seeing this theorem used in many textbooks but none of them provide proof (or there is no text layer so I can't find it!). Here is the statement in *Algebra* (Artin, pg. 540):

> (1.6) **Theorem.**  For any finite extension $K/F$, the order $|G(K/F)|$ of the Galois group divides the degree $[K:F]$ of the extension.

I am brand new to Field Theory and Galois Theory, but this seems rather nontrivial to prove and so I don't know why I am having such trouble finding a book which proves it.

Just to be clear, here is my understanding of a few of the definitions first. If I have misunderstood, please correct me.

The *Galois group* $G(K/F)$ is the set of all automorphisms of $K$ which fix every element of $F$.

The *degree* $[K:F]$ is the dimension of $K$ as an $F$-vector space, that is, the number of vectors in any basis of $K$ where linear combinations are taken with coefficients in $F$.

Could someone please show me a proof of this theorem?

Comment: It's a consequence of Theorem 4.6 on pg. 554, for which a proof is given.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(This answer follows the comment by Brandon Carter.)

Consider $K^G$, the fixed field of $G$. This is a subfield of $K$  such that $[K:K^G]=|G|$. *This is the main non-trivial point.* Since $[K:F]=[K:K^G]\,[K^G:F]$, we conclude that $|G|$ divides $[K:F]$.

Comment: Isn't the order of the Galois group also equal to the degree of extension?

Comment: In the case of a Galois extension, yes.

Comment: I think it's worthy to notice that the Galois group of a finite extension is finite. Only then one can use that $[K:K^G]=|G|$.